# Conditions so that the integral is negative

Tags: calculus, integration

Under which conditions does it hold that $$\int_1^xf(t)\, dt<0$$ ?

Do we maybe have to take the cases $x<1$ and $x>1$ and then :

- If $x>1$ then the integral is negative if $f(t)<0$ for $1<t<x$.
- If $x<1$ then we have that $\int_1^xf(t)\, dt<0\Rightarrow -\int_x^1f(t)\, dt<0 \Rightarrow \int_x^1f(t)\, dt>0$ and so the integral is negative if $f(t)>0$ for $x<t<1$.

Or do we have also other conditions?

Comment: Those would be sufficient conditions (not necessary conditions) provided you fix the sign error in the second case.

Comment: As far as _necessary and sufficient_ conditions go, the only reasonable one would be the statement itself: $\int_1^x f(t)dt < 0$. Trying to write this another "simpler" way would likely be counter-productive as this already seems to be the simplest way. In words: "The area under the curve is negative."

Comment: I fixed the sign in the second case. Is it correct now? @Michael

Comment: Yes this is correct. Because you have used strict inequality everywhere, it is potentially interesting to prove case 1 is sufficient. It would be obvious if we knew $f(t)\leq -\epsilon$ for all $t \in (1,x)$, for some $\epsilon>0$. Of course we cannot guarantee that, but, assuming $1<x$ and $f(t) < 0$ for all $t \in (1,x)$, there must be _some_ $\epsilon>0$ for which the set $\{t  \in (1,x) : f(t)\leq -\epsilon\}$ has positive measure.